# Polymer 2.0 capture long press on dynamically generated paper-cards

Tags: polymer-2.x

Issue: How to select multiple paper-cards and know which ones is selected on user long press/tap on the card.

Description:
I have dynamically generated paper-cards and I render them on the page using template Dom-repeat. At present I have included checkboxes on each paper-card so that the user can select those checkbox associated with the paper-card. That way the user on the screen can select multiple cards on which I can action the next functionality.

I guess the better user experience will be that the user be able to tap or click on the paper-card and be able to hold his finger/mouse for say .5sec and be able to select that card rather than checkbox style selection.

If I am able to get a working code snippet of how a multiple paper-card selection is used then I will be able to provide a better UX for the app.

Current Code Snippet:
(here I am using a paper-icon-button to get the user selected paper-card element).

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{itemsList}}" as="item">
  <paper-card style="float:center; width: 95%" class$="       
    {{_computeCardColorTran(item.type)}}" data-index$="{{item._id}}">
   <paper-icon-button  icon="icons:arrow-drop-down" style="color: 
    grey;" id$="bttn#{{item._id}}" item="[[item]]" on- 
     tap="doSomeDiffAction">
   </paper-icon-button>
       <iron-image class="pad"
                    src="../images/image1"
                    preload
                    sizing="contain"
                    style="" >
                </iron-image>
     </paper-card>
    </template>
```

What I wish to have (something like below) -->

```
 <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{itemsList}}" as="item">
  <paper-card style="float:center; width: 95%" class$="       
    {{_computeCardColorTran(item.type)}}" data-index$="{{item._id}}"

   something-like-user-pressed-longed="
        callFunctionUserPressedForLong"

  >
   <paper-icon-button  icon="icons:arrow-drop-down" style="color: 
    grey;" id$="bttn#{{item._id}}" item="[[item]]" on- 
     tap="doSomeDiffAction">
   </paper-icon-button>
       <iron-image class="pad"
                    src="../images/image1"
                    preload
                    sizing="contain"
                    style="" >
                </iron-image>
     </paper-card>
    </template>
```

And in script javascript function in dom-module I can extract the paper-card selected

```
function callFunctionUserPressedForLong(e){
   var id = e.model.item._id;
   console.log('User pressed for long time on the paper-card = '+ id);
}

function doSomeDiffAction(e){
   var id = e.model.item._id;
   console.log('Not a long press event. User taped or clicked paper card button. Do different action e.g. open popup. = '+ 
   id);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use on-down and on-up events from Polymer and watch time diff between these two events yourself.

In example below, `on-down` and `on-up` event functions are the same for both components (paper-card and paper-icon-button). Inside the `on-down` function (_onDown), the current time is saved to variable. Inside on-up method (_onUp) is detection for tap/click on button (if time diff between on-down and on-up is <0.5s **and** event target is the element with `id=bttn#{{item._id}}` and long-press somewhere inside paper-card (including paper-icon-button).

```js
_onDown(e) {
  this.startTime = Date.now()
}
_onUp(e) {
  let id = e.model.item._id;
  //stopPropagation because this is otherwise called twice - from paper-card and from paper-icon-button
  e.stopPropagation()
  let id = "1"
  if (Date.now() - this.startTime > 500) {
    console.log(`long press somewhere inside paper-card :: id=${id}`);
  } else if (e.target.id == `bttn#${id}`) {
    console.log(`Not a long press event. User taped or clicked paper card button :: id=${id}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<paper-card on-down="_onDown" on-up="_onUp">
  <paper-icon-button on-down="_onDown" on-up="_onUp">Tap me</paper-icon-button>
</paper-card>
```